# Yet another LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: unresolved-external, lnk2019

I'm creating a backbone for a school project, but I'm running into "unresolved external symbol" errors. According to previous problems mentioned on this site, I think have to manually link my project to a .lib file. Problem is, I don't know exactly which .lib I need to link to. Can someone explain like I'm twelve?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Birthday311, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2/2/2012 07:55:30 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Birthday311.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>birthday_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Birthday::getDay(void)const " (?getDay@Birthday@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl test_class_Birthday_default_ctor(class Tester &)" (?test_class_Birthday_default_ctor@@YAXAAVTester@@@Z)
1>birthday_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Birthday::getMonth(void)const " (?getMonth@Birthday@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl test_class_Birthday_default_ctor(class Tester &)" (?test_class_Birthday_default_ctor@@YAXAAVTester@@@Z)
1>birthday_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Birthday::getName(void)const " (?getName@Birthday@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl test_class_Birthday_default_ctor(class Tester &)" (?test_class_Birthday_default_ctor@@YAXAAVTester@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Ender\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Birthday311\Debug\Birthday311.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Comment: How should *we* know which `.lib` file? Which one contains the definitions for the `Birthday::getDay` and `Birthday::getMonth` functions? Those aren't part of any standard library that I'm aware of, so you had to have written them yourself.

Comment: Oh, you helped me figure out the right answer. Taking a look at my .cpp file, I realized that I simply called the getDay and getMonth functions as `int getDay()` instead of `int Birthday::getDay() const`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you didn't actually implement the functions getDay, getMonth, and getName.

Comment: Oh, you helped me figure out the right answer. Taking a look at my .cpp file, I realized that I simply called the getDay and getMonth functions as 'int getDay()' instead of 'int Birthday::getDay() const'. Basically, I didn't implement the getDay and getMonth functions properly. Thanks!